Expo-video problem with replaying every time the screen is focused
I have been working with the expo-av library, but with the recent release of a stable version of the expo-video library in Expo SDK 52, I decided to give it a try. However, I came across an issue that I wasn't having in expo-av. Whenever I want to redirect right back and to replay the video from the beginning, it doesn't happen. How can I adjust the code to make sure the video restarts from the start after being redirected to?
To explain what I am trying to achieve, here my original code in expo-av.
Screen 1:
On this screen, the video is rendered, and to ensure it plays when the screen is focused, a useFocusEffect from expo-router is used, along with a useCallback hook.
useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      const replayVideo = async () => {
        if (videoRef.current) {
          try {
            await videoRef.current.setPositionAsync(0); // Reset position to beginning
            await videoRef.current.playAsync(); // Start playback again
          } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error replaying video:', error);
          }
        }
      };
      replayVideo();
    }, [])
  );

return (
 <Video
   ref={videoRef}
   source={{ uri: videoData.url }}
   isLooping={false}
   shouldPlay={true}
   resizeMode={ResizeMode.COVER}
   onPlaybackStatusUpdate={handleStatusUpdate}
 />
)


Screen 2:
Here I have rendered a button with a function.
 const handleGoBack = () => {
    router.back();
  };

I've tried approaching the expo-video with useEventListener from expo or useEffect from react. Lastly, I applied the useFocusEffect as it is above with expo-av, but that didn't work either and the video would not start playing from the start.
Here is the latest version of the code for the video.
useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      if (player) {
        player.seekBy(0);
        player.play();
      }
    }, [player])
  );


return (
  <VideoView
    style={{ width: 400, height: 400 }}
    player={player}
    allowsPictureInPicture
    nativeControls={false}
  />
);

